# 32bit MAPI-based app running under 64bit Outlook?

Tags: outlook, 64-bit, 32-bit, mapi

I have an app using 32bit MAPI. Now I want to run it under a target system with 64bit Outlook installed. I know the app cannot work with the 64bit MAPI system. So I wonder if there is a way to install a 32bit MAPI subsystem, or some hotfix on the target system so that the app can work?

Comment: what benefits do you perceive running 64bit versions of office?

Comment: Fewer angry clients who are running the 64 bit version of Office installed on their machines out of the box or due to the management decision to standartize on the 64 bit version of Office.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the standalone verson of MAPI from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&DisplayLang=en, but it will refuse to instal if OUtlook is already present. It does not check the Outlook bitness.
In other words, there is nothing you can do short of recompiling your app in 64 bit.